# Bootstrap - different 100% width menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I want to make 100% width sub-menu. This should not be 100% of navbar width but 100% of width page. I'm trying to setup this but I can't manage this to work. Is there any way to style `ul.sub-menu` as 100% width of page?

There is many solution for 100% width but it's always 100% of navbar width not page.

This is an image showing whant I try to achive. If you click for example contact and contact have sub menu, sub menu shows on whole width page.

Thx for all kind of help.

[image: wireframe of what I want to do]

Answer (score 0):

You can use 2 static top nav bars for this, without adding them to your `.col-sx-12`

The top one will need `margin-bottom: 0;` added to it.

Make sure you change the `data-target` of each collapse button.

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse-1"
```

and

```
data-target=".navbar-collapse-2"
```

respectively. These classes also need added to the appropriate `div`, per the fiddle.

Fiddle:
[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MDEJ9/)

Comment: This is nice aproach but second navbar need to show sub-menu items form first navbar.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to get this working completely.  I ended up settling for using data-toggle with a target ul.  Sorry for all the junk in the markup but the primary parts of the code are the `data-toggle="collapse"` and `data-target="#menu*"` attributes.  There are two submenus under "Courses & Rates" and "Clubs & Leagues"  both `div`s are 100% width and the child `ul`s have `.container`.  Of course you can't have a parent container for the nav.

```
<!-- primary nav -->
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right primary">
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="collapsed no-transition" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1">Courses &amp; Rates <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <div class="collapse no-transition" id="menu1">
            <ul class="container">
                <li><a href="/course/elmwood/">Elmwood Golf Course</a></li>
                <li><a href="/course/prairie-green/">Prairie Green Golf Course</a></li>
                <li><a href="/course/kuehn-park/">Kuehn Park Golf Course</a></li>
                <li><a href="/green-fees/">Green Fees</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <li class="dropdown">
        <a href="#" class="collapsed no-transition" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu2">Clubs &amp; Leagues <b class="caret"></b></a>
        <div class="collapse no-transition" id="menu2">
            <ul class="container">
                <li><a href="/clubs-and-leagues/mens-golf-club/">Sioux Falls Men's Golf Club</a></li>
                <li><a href="/clubs-and-leagues/ladies-clubs">Ladies Golf Leagues</a></li>
                <li><a href="/clubs-and-leagues/junior-golf/">Junior Golf</a></li>
                <li><a href="/clubs-and-leagues/high-school-golf/">High School Golf</a></li>
                <li><a href="/clubs-and-leagues/first-tee/">The First Tee</a></li>
                <li><a href="/clubs-and-leagues/rockafellow-scholarship/">Rockafellow Scholarship</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <li><a href="/events/">Events</a></li>
    <li><a href="/news/">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="/shop/">Pro Shop</a></li>
</ul><!-- end primary nav -->
```

EDIT: note that this requires bootstrap's dorpdown js and css

EDIT2: [docs here](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#dropdowns)